# Return ID if sum of value is between two possible date ranges, and output which date range it came from?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has a similar structure as this:

| UserID | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 50 | 01/01/2021 |
| 234 | 105 | 02/01/2021 |
| 123 | 60 | 01/15/2021 |
| 345 | 70 | 01/15/2021 |
| 456 | 110 | 12/31/2020 |
| 345 | 50 | 02/15/2020 |

I have two date ranges, *01/01/2021 - 01/31/2021* and *02/01/2021 - 02/28/2021*. I want to get a list of UserIDs if they had total amount >= 100 within these date ranges, and to specify which date range it came from.

So in this example, I'd like an output like this:

| UserID | Total Amount | Date Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 110 | January |
| 234 | 105 | February |

User ID 345 and 456 would not be included since their total amounts only reached >= 100 outside of the date ranges.

In my code, I'm not sure how to exclude UserID 345 since technically they have an amount >= 100 coming from dates in both ranges and not just one single range.

I'm having troubles with only summing if it's within the date range and I'm not sure how to specify from which date range it's coming from:

```
SELECT
   UserID
   ,SUM(amount)
FROM table
WHERE
   date BETWEEN '01-01-2021' AND '01-31-2021' OR
   date BETWEEN '02-01-2021' AND '02-28-2021'
GROUP BY 
   UserID
HAVING SUM(amount) >= 100
```

Comment: Would it always be two date ranges or might you have many?

Comment: There could be other date ranges in the future, I actually simplified in the example a bit. The date ranges I'm actually working with are 01/15/2021-01/31/2021 and 02/01/2021-02/28/2021. So not always whole months.

Comment: I mean would the query be for two configurable date ranges or might you want to query any number of ranges **at the same time**?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CROSS APPLY` to calculate the date range, and then group by it.

But in this instance, it appears you are just using whole months, so we can just use `DATENAME`.

Side notes:

1. You should not use `mm-dd-yyyy` format for date literals
2. You can combine your two periods together in this instance, I have not done so to leave you the option of disjoint periods.

```sql
SELECT t.UserID,
       SUM(t.amount),
       Month = DATENAME(month, t.date)
FROM table t
WHERE t.Date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-31' OR
    t.date BETWEEN '2021-02-01' AND '2021-02-28'
GROUP BY UserId, DATENAME(month, t.date);
```

**NOTE:** if your dates are actually `datetime` values then your filter is wrong. Instead you must use a half open interval:

```sql
WHERE t.Date >= '2021-01-01' AND t.Date < '2021-02-01' OR
    t.date >= '2021-02-01' AND t.Date < '2021-03-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date ranges are months, you can join to the ranges and then aggregate by user:

```
select min(range_name), user_name, sum(amount)
from t join
     (values ('2021-01-01', '2021-01-31', 'January'),
             ('2021-02-01', '2021-02-28', 'February')
     ) v(range_start, range_end, range_name)
     on t.date >= v.range_start and t.date <= v.range_end        
group by userid
having count(distinct range_name) = 1 and
       sum(amount) > 100;
```

The `having` clause limits the results both by the number of ranges and by the amount.

If you just wants months between particular dates, I would simplify this to:

```
select datepart(month, min(date)), userid, sum(amount)
from t
where date >= '2021-01-01' and date < '2021-03-01'
group by userid
having count(distinct month(date)) = 1 and
       sum(amount) > 100;
```